# Whats the Azure PowerShell equivalent to "az configure --defaults location=foo"?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cli

For managing defaults we can use the `configure` subcommand.

```
Az configure \
  --defaults group=<my resource group> \
  --defaults location=<my prefered location>
```

With Azure PowerShell we have `Set-AzDefault`, which lets me set the default resource group but not the location.

```
Set-AzDefault -ResourceGroupName <my resource group>
```

What would be the PowerShell equivalent to Azure CLI example from above?

Comment: Hi, do you know how to use `Set-AzDefault -ResourceGroupName <my resource group>`? e.g. after setting it, `Get-AzWebApp` still list all the webapps in the whole subscription. But if use `az configure --defaults group=xxx`, `az webapp list` will just list the webapps in `xxx` group, no need to pass the `--resource-group` parameter.